# How to cross compile gdbserver to different platform?

Tags: gdb, mips, cross-compiling, configure, gdbserver

I'm trying to compile gdbserver for the purpose of remote debugging on an embedded MIPs platform. I have a cross compiler GCC, binutils, and gdb compiled for the platform.

My configure command is as so

```
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX --target=$TARGET --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

However, it keeps building with my system compiler rather than the cross-compiler, so I get errors. How can I configure this to build with the cross compiler so that I can run gdbserver on the embedded platform and then debug it from my PC?

Answer (score 2):

You want --host, not --target.